# Trying update and save a value for product meta data on woocommerce cart

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to figure out how can I make the value on the product meta data shown on the cart to be editable and saved when clicking the `update quote` button. When I try to update the value on the `BOP` field for each product, it does not reflect properly

[image]

[image]

I've made some work in progress but can never seem to make it work

**cart.php**

```
    <?php
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
        $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

            <td class="product-remove">
                <?php
                    echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                        'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                        sprintf(
                            '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                            esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                            esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                            esc_attr( $product_id ),
                            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                        ),
                        $cart_item_key
                    );
                ?>
            </td>

            <td class="product-thumbnail">
            <?php
            $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
            } else {
                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
            }
            ?>
            </td>

            <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
            <?php
            if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
            } else {
                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
            }

            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            ?>

            
            <?php 
            // Meta data.
            // echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok. ?>


            <div class="box-type-field">
                <span>BOP: <input class="box-type"  cart_item_key="<?php echo $cart_item['key'] ?>" type="number" value="<?php echo $cart_item['BOP'] ?>" /></span>
            </div>
            
            <?php

            // Backorder notification.
            if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
            }
            ?>
            </td>

            

            <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
            <?php
            if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
            } else {
                $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
                    array(
                        'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                        'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                        'max_value'    => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                        'min_value'    => '0',
                        'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
                    ),
                    $_product,
                    false
                );
            }

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
            ?>
            </td>

            
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

---

**JS**

```
jQuery('.box-type-field .box-type').on('change', function () {

    var cartItemKey = jQuery(this).attr("cart_item_key");
    var boxType = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "post", 
        url : '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        data : {
            action : "update_cart_boxtype",
            cart_item_key : cartItemKey,
            box_type : boxType,
        },
        success: function(cartItem) {
            cartItemKey = cartItem[0];
            cartItemQty = cartItem[1];
            if (cartItem) jQuery('input[name="cart['+cartItemKey+'][qty]"]').val(cartItemQty); // update quantity 

            jQuery('.woocommerce-cart-form button[type="submit"]').click(); // submit form
        }
    })
})
```

---

**PHP (functions.php)**

```
  function update_cart_boxtype_init() {
  if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
      $cart_item_key = (isset($_POST['cart_item_key']))?$_POST['cart_item_key'] : '';
      $cart_item = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ];
      $box_type = (isset($_POST['box_type']))?$_POST['box_type'] : '';
      $cart_updated = false;

      $cart_item_key_new = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'], $cart_item['variation'], ['box-type'=>$box_type] );

      $found = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_item_key_new );

      if ($found != '') {
          $new_qty = $cart_item['quantity'] + WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key_new ]['quantity'];
          WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
          wp_send_json_success([$cart_item_key_new, $new_qty]);
      } else {
          WC()->cart->add_to_cart($cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['quantity'], $cart_item['variation_id'], $cart_item['variation'], ['box-type' => $box_type]);
          $cart_updated = true;
          WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
          wp_send_json_success(false);
      }
  }
  wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_cart_boxtype', 'update_cart_boxtype_init' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_cart_boxtype', 'update_cart_boxtype_init' );
```

---

**Some errors indicated:**

1.) When I try to update the value it returns 404 on the console as shown below

[image]

Comment: Which part is not working?

Comment: @Moishy The part where the product meta data `(BOP)` is not updating when saving or updating the data. With regards to code, it's hard to point out what's the issue.

Comment: I put a bounty on it to help me if anyone can resolve it.

Comment: what error are you getting if any?

Comment: @Moishy one of the issues is I'm getting an AJAX 404 whenever I click on the `update quote`. button. I've attached a screenshot for reference

Comment: url : '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'. Are you sure that your site URL is http://localhost/wp-admin and not http://localhost/YOURSITE/wp-admin ? Try to set the full URL in hard in your code then try the more complete answer of @Moishy. Also, i'm seeing a potential mistake where your field name is not "BOP" but "Field" with one value "BOP". Is it what you want ? I have never worked with woocommerce attributes, so i don't know if it's something normal.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your ajax function I will say that when you define this `wp_send_json_success(false);` your javascript is expecting an array of something and you are submitting a boolean.

if you are getting a 404 error then it seems like your ajax url is wrong:

you can define it on the page as a [`localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to an [`enqueued script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

```
$args = array( 
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
);
wp_localize_script( 'YOUR_ENQUEUED_SCRIPT', 'ajax', $args );
```

and call it in your js:

```
ajax.ajaxurl
```

or defined in the theme:

```
<?php $ajax_url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>
<?php echo $ajax_url; ?>
```